# Smash up: First mate with ongoing actions attached to it. Do the actions follow him?

Tags: smash-up

I'd like to hear peoples opinion on this.

The text on the cards mentioned below:

First Mate: "Special: After this base i scored, you may move this minion to another base instead of the discard pile".

Heirloom: Play on a minion. Ongoing: This card gives this minion +1 power for each Heirloom on it. This card cannot be destroyed.(the "this cards cannot be destroyed" is irrelivant to my question).

Situation:

- First mate with an ongoing action (fx. heirloom) played on it(first mate).
- The base scores
- the first mate gets to move to another base after the base i scored

question: does the action played on him follow him or does it get discarded?

I'd think that it would follow him.

Comment: Actions played on minions are attached to those minions, and (unless stated otherwise) they move around with the minion regardless of why that minion moves around.

Answer (score 3):

They follow him.

> *After scoring, players can use Special abilities that
>   happen “after” a base scores. Then all cards still on that base go to their owners’ discard piles.*

The First Mate is no longer on the base, so he doesn't get discarded, much less actions attached to him.